# Last Eclipse update causes referenced libraries couldn't be used

Tags: android, eclipse

After the last update of Eclipse, I can't get my workspace working again.
I've tried several workarounds and redo of configuration actions and there is one issue that I can't solve, and figure out why.

**The last update:**
The last Eclipse update adds a new line in the classpath. I don't know what is that, but I've googled it and I think that is causing the issue. BTW, I've tried with and without this line in the classpath file.

```
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES"/>
```

**Here the problem:**
I've 3 libraries that use in my project (one for sliding menues, one for google maps, and one for pull to refresh feature). All of it compiles without any issue.

I've a project that uses these libraries. Till the last update, everything works fine, Android libraries referenced by Project properties -> Android -> Libraries, worked ok, and all the classes could be used in the project. After the update, although the references are visible and looks ok in the linked libraries (Project properties -> Android -> Libraries), the use of referenced classes in the project gives the error that the type cannot be resolved.

I'm struggling with this from days ago with out any solution. I've tried to rollback the adt version, and ends with a very unstable eclipse (where I can't even import my projects to the workspace, because the Finish button of the import process don't work). And I've updated to the last version, looking to solve the continuous crash of the eclipse shortcuts.

ADT installed: Android Development Tools 22.0.0.v201305140200--675183

Any help with this will be appreciated!

Milton.

Comment: @Selvin, you pointed me to the right answer. I haven't found it yesterday... Tks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after the update to ADT 22.

It is a known bug and you can solve it, by activating something in the library you want to refer:

1. Right click on the library project -> Properties
2. Java Build Path and open the tab: Order and Export
3. Check "Android Private Libraries"

Then clean everything, your library and the other project, and it will work.